# File not found when importing figures produced by gnuplot (epslatex) from another folder

Tags: input, epslatex

I have recently started using gnuplot's epslatex terminal to create graphs to a report I am writing. I have, however, encountered an unexpected problem. I usually keep my chapters and figures in separate folders while the main file `main.tex` is kept at top level. The problem arises when I try to import an image using `\input` in one of my chapters.

**Example**

I have a chapter `Chapters/theory.tex` (imported in `main.tex` with `\input`)  in which I would like to import the figure `Figures/graph.tex`. But when I run

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \begin{center}
        \input{Figures/graph}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

I get the error "File 'graph' not found".

I tried to move `graph.tex` and `graph.eps` up one level so that they are in the same folder as the main file and changed `Chapters/theory.tex` to

```
\input{Figures/testToSeeIfThePathIsCorrect}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \begin{center}
        %\input{Figures/graph}
        \input{graph}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

this time everything compiled without a problem. I also added a test file `Figures/testToSeeIfThePathIsCorrect` with just plain text to see if something was wrong with the path but this was no problem either.

**Question**

Why do I get an error when I import the image as `Figures/graph.tex` but not when I import it as `graph.tex`? Expecially since I can import any other "ordinary" `.tex` file in `/Figures`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by manually changing the `\includegraphics{graph}` command in `Figures/graph.tex` to `\includegraphics{Figures/graph}`. I really should have thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

In order not to have to change all your files, an easier way is to include this in your preamble: `\graphicspath{Figures/}`

In this way, the command `\includegraphics{graph}` would by default be searching in the Figures path.